# How to prevent someone from modifying the input form parameters from the Browser in JSP/Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Consider the scenario as below:

I have a HTML form.

```
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="1" >Radio One<br>
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="2"> Radio Two
```

I am reading the input provided by the user in one of my servlet as:

```
int radioype = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("radioButton"));
```

Now I dont need a null check because I know that this value is not going to be null.
The value can be 1 or 2 so it will be successfully parsed as as int. But however any body could change the value of `radioButton` (for e.g. by using FireBug) to something else. This will create a lot of trouble for my application.

What is the best way to deal with this situation? There are number of such inputs in my application including text boxes, dropdowns, text areas etc. I agree that I will have to validate text boxes on my own. But these checkboxes and radio buttons seem to be too much of validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already identified the real problem - the user can use something like Firebug to send back anything they like, including null for these parameters. There's no getting round the fact that you need to validate everything which comes from a browser form. Doing otherwise makes your application insecure and liable to hacking.

I'd recommend using one of the many Java web frameworks available, which make the creation of a validation layer in your applications relatively easy (e.g.: Spring-MVC or Struts 2).

Comment: Pretty much all of them will have something, Spring MVC and Struts 2 are a couple of the most used ones.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way around this. You simply can't stop someone who wants to change the request values to do so, so you will have to validate it in your code. Maybe the best thing you can do is to implement the most generic validation layer you can, so you can easily apply it to all existing code without the need to make big changes.

On the other hand, if, for example, you have a gender radio button, with values `M` and `F`, if someone submits `J` in there, it's perfectly fine to give them a well handled exception message.

Comment: Probably I can write some of the validation code in my setter methods. Since I know that gender can be 'M' or 'F', I can ask the setter method itself to throw an exception if anything else is passe.

Comment: You could consider a validation service through which every request would pass. You could validate the param value in regard to param name, and also pass in some context, in case the same name for a param can be used in different situations with different values (for example, `some_id` might be integer in most cases, but string in a few other cases, you could tell that apart by providing a context).

Answer (score 0):

Anything that goes from client to server is not under your control and observation. So you need to implement all your validation methods in the backend.

Backend validation is a must, not an option. I've seen many people who relied on client-side input validation and had big big troubles. Read about SQL injection for examples.

A very basic backend validation process covers all the checks in the client side, though most of them cover more cases. You can generalize the checks and mark the inputs accordingly to not go over all the inputs one by one.

For further information, here are your keywords: java, jsp, backend, validation, form, input